# JQuery Easing Not Working in asp.net mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am  using the below code to show data on my web page with some animate effect

```
    .done(function (response) {
     $(".loadig-overlay").hide();
                $('#Container').toggle('slide', {
                     direction: 'left'
                 }, 250, function () {
                     $("#Container").html(response);
                     $('#Container').toggle('slide', {
                         direction: 'right'
                     }, 250);
                 });
})
```

The #container html gets  replaced by that received in the response but the animate effect is not applied

Answer (score 0):

```js
                $('#Container').toggle('slide', {
                     direction: 'left'
                 }, 500, function () {
                     $("#Container").html('abc');
                     $('#Container').toggle('slide', {
                         direction: 'right'
                     }, 500);
                 });
```

```html
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="Container">

</div>
```

It appears that everything is okay with your script. Only thing which comes to my mind is that element containing 'Container' is too small so you don't see the effect. Or maybe you've been playing with z-index of neighbouring elements?

Comment: The container element is not small.  The div with class loading-overlay is actually a loader & surely has an z-index property & is the child element of container. Is that not working only coz of z-index or some other reason @Marek Piotrowski